# iOS Swift How to change or update UILabel attribute in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to update/change a UILabel attribute (background color,background shape,etc...) dynamically when I get data from a Web service.

I want to dispaly this Label in difference type by different Lable text, update UILabel attribute according the testdata which got from web server. like that : if get testdata=[1,1,1,1] the UIlabel background color is red , testdata=[2,2,2,2] UILabel background color is blue.etc

I am doing the following:

**In Main.Stroyboard:**

I add TableView and TableViewCell (choice custom) associated `UITableViewCell` named `TVcell` and add a UILabel component.

**In TVcell**

```
import UIKit
class TVCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    var testdata:TestDataInfo?{
        didSet{
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    private func updateUI(){
        if let mFildata=testdata{
            setStautesLabel()
        }
    }

    private func setStautesLabel(){
        self.testLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 35))
        self.testLabel.text = "thisTestLabel"

        self.testLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.2)
        self.superview?.addSubview(self.testLabel)
    }
}
```

**Methode 1: In TableViewController**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = TestDataInfo![indexPath.row]
    let cell = self.TV.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.ProjectAppliedCellIndentifier,forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let filesDataCell = cell as? TVCell{
        filesDataCell.testdata=data
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Result 1**

Just One Cell testLabel has been change and rest Cell no display testLabel

**Methode 2: In TableViewController**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = TestDataInfo![indexPath.row]
    let cell = self.TV.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.ProjectAppliedCellIndentifier,forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let filesDataCell = cell as? TVCell{
        filesDataCell.testdata=data
        // update testLable In there
        let testLable:UILabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 35))
        testLable.text = "thisLabel"
        testLable.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.2)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(testLable)
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Result 2**

can display TestUILabel in all cell. but not update testLabel original just add new UILabel

but why ? I want to update all UILable in TVCell. Can anyone Help me?

Comment: updateUI meants I want to dispaly it in difference type by different Lable text, I have wrote i want to update UILabel attribute according the testdata which got from web server. like that : if get testdata=1 the UIlabel background color is red , testdata=2 UILabel background color is blue.etc

Answer (score 1):

Don't create new instance of testLabel in TableViewController. You can directly access it in TableViewController by filesDataCell.testLabel; Since cells are reused, adding new label will keep on adding new labels without discarding previous labels.

Comment: ok ,but have any method  update it in TVcell(TaleviewCell class)

Comment: @sach, "adding new label will keep on adding new labels without discarding previous labels.", what is the best solution to create labels dynamically or based on model data count in UITableVIew?